# Create Blank row after each two rows using Scrapy Python

Tags: python, scrapy, scrapy-pipeline

I want to create the blank row after each two rows in csv. Is there any way to do that?

Output I want:
[image]

Here is my code :

```
      # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy
import re

class AaSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'aa'
    allowed_domains = ['covers.com']
    year = int(input('Enter the Year:'))
    s = int(input('Enter Start of the month:'))
    e = int(input('Enter End of the month:'))

    # start_urls = ['https://www.covers.com/sports/MLB/matchups?selectedDate=2021-4-5']

    def start_requests(self):

        for i in range((self.s), (int(self.e)+1)):
            url = f'https://www.covers.com/sports/MLB/matchups?selectedDate={self.year}-{i}-1'
            for a in range(1,31):
                ab = ((url[:-1]) + str(a))
                yield scrapy.Request(url = ab,callback= self.parse)
      
    def filter(self , x):
        regex = re.compile('[^a-zA-Z]')
        regex.sub('', x)

    def parse(self, response):
        # count = 1
        
 

        for count ,data in enumerate(response.xpath('//div[@class="cmg_matchup_line_score"]/table/tbody/tr')):
            if count % 3 == 0:

                a = data.xpath('./td[position() = count((//div[@class="cmg_matchup_line_score"])[1]/table/thead//th[text() = "X"]/preceding-sibling::th)+1]/text()').extract()
                yield{
                    'Date': '',
                    'Team': '',
                    '1': '',
                    '2': '',
                    '3': '',
                    '4': '',
                    '5': '',
                    '6': '',
                    '7': '',
                    '8': '',
                    '9': '',
                    'X': '',
                    'R': '',
                    'ML': '',
                    'O/U': '',
                    'H': '',
                    'E': '',
                    
                }
                
            else:
                a = data.xpath('./td[position() = count((//div[@class="cmg_matchup_line_score"])[1]/table/thead//th[text() = "X"]/preceding-sibling::th)+1]/text()').extract()
                yield{
                    'Date': ((response.url).split('=')[1]),
                    'Team': data.xpath('./td[1]/text()').get(),
                    '1': data.xpath('./td[2]/text()').get(),
                    '2': data.xpath('./td[3]/text()').get(),
                    '3': data.xpath('./td[4]/text()').get(),
                    '4': data.xpath('./td[5]/text()').get(),
                    '5': data.xpath('./td[6]/text()').get(),
                    '6': data.xpath('./td[7]/text()').get(),
                    '7': data.xpath('./td[8]/text()').get(),
                    '8': data.xpath('./td[9]/text()').get(),
                    '9': data.xpath('./td[10]/text()').get(),
                    'X': [i for i in a if not i.replace(" ", "").replace("_", "").isalpha()],
                    'R': data.xpath('./td[11]/text()').get(),
                    'ML': data.xpath('./td[12]/text()').get(),
                    'O/U': data.xpath('./td[13]/text()').get(),
                    'H': data.xpath('./td[14]/text()').get(),
                    'E': data.xpath('./td[15]/text()').get(),
                    
                }
```

Is there any way to create blank rows after each two rows. Thank you

I have try this method but it won't work. and I am getting the results like sometime blank rows after 3 rows and some time after one rows

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with scrapy. However, I would try to leverage:

```
if count % 3 == 0
```

You can initialise count outside 'for' loop and increment it by 1 inside 'for' loop and whenever above condition is true, you can write logic to insert a blank row before inserting data in csv. This will essentially insert a blank row whenever the count is 3,6,9,12, etc meaning 2 rows will be the data and 3rd row will be a blank row.

Comment: I have tried this but they will not get the desired result

Comment: @NoobGamer This would have been similar to the answer I'd have given. Why didn't it work? What result did you get?

Comment: Its sometime create blank row after two rows and sometime create blank rows after one row or more

Comment: @NoobGamer I tried something similar and it works so I'd be interested to see exactly what you tried?

Comment: @tomjn , I have update the code please check it but it won't work

Comment: @NoobGamer what you've put there isn't right... and I don't think it was really what @captaink was suggesting. It should not be an `if/else` just an `if`. The part you have in the `else` should always be executed. My proposal would be to just have `if if i % 2: yield {}` after your original yield which works.

Comment: okay I need to initialize i = 0 and then apply the condition if 1%2: yield{}

Comment: That's you are trying to say?

Comment: Keep your `enumerate`. In the version of your code above delete the entire `if count % 3 == 0:` keeping only the code in the `else` (but obviously remove the `else`). Then immediately after your `yield {...}` add `if count % 2: yield {}`. If this isn't clear then I can write an answer but I feel like @captaink should get some credit

Comment: Thanks tomjn. Noob Gamer, like @tomjn mentioned, I was suggesting to keep the 'blank row if condition' as an additional logic. There shouldn't be any else part to that if condition. Your updated code above looks good. You just need to remove the 'else' when inserting actual data. This will make sure that your data gets inserted and the blank row will be inserted in same for loop when 'if count % 3 == 0' returns true.